# python check if user input has the correct int value in a string

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers, user-input

I try to fix a problem where the user can input for example "blub1234" or "blub4567" or "blub912" and the code can check if the user typed in the right word "blub" and the possible value as an int from 1 up to 100k.

```
user_input = str("Type your blub User")
if user_input == ("user_input" + ???):
    print("Okay")
else:
    print("Not Okay")
```

The user shouldn't type for example "blob2312" or "blib1212" only the word "blub" with the number value to 100k. I tried it with ranges and for loops, but it ends every time with:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: You should look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) There are lots of answers which try to validate input.

Comment:  https://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

you could use `regex`:

```
import re
String_Attached_To_String = 123
user_input = input("String")
re.findall(r"{}(\d+)".format(String_Attached_To_String),user_input)
```

Comment: You do realise that your program will print out: ` ... is not Okay` at least 99999 times?

Comment: holy cow, just don’t use a range loop which runs for 10k times! It doesn’t matter what it does, but at least performance will hurt.

Comment: @rv.kvetch i removed the issue you pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

If you know both the string and the int and just want to check if the input is equal to that fixed combination you can do:

```
pw_int = 1234
pw_str = "blob"

    if user_input == (pw_str + str(pw_int)):
        print(f"PW was {pw_str}{pw_int} -> Okay")
    else:
        print("Not Okay")
```

Comment: this is not what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score -2):

```
user_input = str("Type your blub User")
if user_input == "blub100k:"
   print("Okay")
else:
   print("Not Okay")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?